# C++ Get an address off of a pointer

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to understand C++ way of Reading/Writing in memory.
What I have is, I'm trying to get an address off of a pointer. I have the pointer which will point to my desired address.
Like I have the current address I want to use to read the value, let's say the address is **14C9862** but as every time I run the program again this address changes. I have the pointer which writes to this address (I'm using cheat engine) and it says the pointer is equal to **eax+ePSXE.exe+A82020** as for **eax = 77420** and **ePSXE.exe = 1718**(ignoring the zeros), so **how could I write this in C++ in a way that I can get the ADDRESS every time I run the program again.**

Current code:

```
int readTest {}       
ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPBYTE*)ePSXe+pointer?, &readTest, sizeof(readTest), 0);
        std::cout << readTest << std::endl;
```

As I'm thinking now LPBYTE is a pointer to a byte so couldn't it be like **`(A82020*)????`** I'm just going insane I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your target address can be calculated if you know the base address of the `ePSXE.exe` module.

You could get it with use of the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h> 

DWORD procId = 0;   // <-- Replace with real process ID
MODULEENTRY32 lpModuleEntry = {0};
HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, procId);
if(!hSnapShot)
{
  return NULL;
}

DWORD baseAddress = 0;
lpModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(lpModuleEntry);
BOOL bModule = Module32First( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
while(bModule)
{
  if(!strcmp( lpModuleEntry.szModule, "ePSXE.exe") )
  {
    CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
    baseAddress = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(lpModuleEntry.modBaseAddr);
  }
  bModule = Module32Next( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
}
CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
```

Finally you need to combine static part of address with the module base address:

```
ReadProcessMemory(handle, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(baseAddress + 0xA82020), &readTest, sizeof(readTest), NULL);
```

Comment: Isn't lpModuleEntry.szModule supposed to be a const char instead of a WCHAR? Visual is giving me a error

Comment: @MatthewSouza Actually, it's `TCHAR`, which is `wchar_t` when your project configured for Unicode character set. The code above is not tested, it should give you an idea of how to deal with the address.

Comment: Thank you your response is indeed correct, it worked! But without the EAX value it gives a random number from another adress. I don't know half of the things you wrote, but I'm going to study it really hard on it. Thanks for your response!